# Rewrite and "host" urls on own domain

Tags: nginx

If i go to site https://example.com/media/https://google.com/imageurl 
I want that the url openes the site after /media.

So i want to open https://google.com/imageurl but not a complete redirect.

It must stay on my domain, is that working?

I tried something like that, but not working :/

```
rewrite ^/media/(.*).(png|jpg|gif) $1.$2 ;
```

So everything after /media/ i will display show on my own domain, is something that working?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is calling "transparent proxying". You cannot do this with simple rewrite. You can try this:

```
location ~ ^/media/(?<proto>https?:)/+(?<domain>[^/]+)(?<subreq>/.+\.(?:png|jpg|gif))$ {
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    proxy_set_header Host $domain;
    proxy_pass $proto//$domain$subreq;
}
```

or this:

```
location ~ ^/media/(?<proto>https?:)/+(?<domain>[^/]+)(?<subreq>/.+\.(?:png|jpg|gif))$ {
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    proxy_set_header Host $domain;
    rewrite .* $subreq break;
    proxy_pass $proto//$domain;
}
```

You will also need a [`resolver`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) directive in your config to use this.